# json_encode strings with special characters and spaces

Tags: json, symfony, twig

Which filter do I need to `json_encode` a string with special characters and spaces? Is there maybe any better approach to pass a `json` object with the translated strings from `twig` variables to a template in `Vue.js`?

I tried this;

```
{# renders: äeiöü #}
<p>{{'string1'|trans}}</p>
{# renders: this is a string with spaces #}
<p>{{'string2'|trans}}</p>

{% set snippets = {
 string1: 'string1'|trans,
 string2: 'string2'|trans,
 } %}

<div id="app"  snippet={{ snippets|json_encode }}>
  <demo></demo>
</div>

<script>
  let snippetJSON = document.getElementById('app').getAttribute('snippet');

  //Output: {"string1":"\u00e4ei\u00f6\u00fc","string2":"this
  console.log(snippetJSON);
</script>
```

Comment: `json_encode` can deal with "special˝ characters perfectly fine.

Comment: thanks you are right. But what about strings with whitespaces? it works without problems when i pass a single word in the string but not with whole sentences.

Comment: You probably need to enclose the attribute with quotes? `snippet="{{ .. }}"`

Comment: yes that was it. thanks a lot!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @deceze in the comments. The attribute had to be in quotes. Also @WPhil is right, the JSON.parse() part was also missing.

Comment: This is not answer, please submit feedback like this as a comment instead.

Answer (score -1):

You need to use `JSON.parse()` to decode the orignial values.